# nohup java -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/var/log/hlrs_gc.log -cp .... 1>&- 2>... &,application log write to gc log file

Tags: java, linux, logging

I run a command like'nohup java  -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/var/log/hlrs_gc.log -cp ....   1>&- 2>...   &' .
The application log is written into hlrs_gc.log .
Is &-  mean close the output stream 1? 
Why the output redirect to gc log file?

Comment: Because `loggc` outputs to a file. It has nothing to do with standard out or standard error (/dev/fd0 or /dev/fd1).

Comment: If i run 'nohup java -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/var/log/hlrs_gc.log -cp .... 1>/dev/null 2>... &'.The hlrs_gc.log only have gc log.If i run '1>&-',the hlrs_gc.log both have gc log and application log.

Comment: You are looking at some [bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131801/closing-a-file-descriptor-vs)-ism there. Good luck.